# $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\phi(x,y,k) + \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}\phi(x,y,k) = -k^2.\phi(x,y,k)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Any idea of how can I solve the differential equation $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\phi(x,y,k) + \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}\phi(x,y,k) = -k^2.\phi(x,y,k)$? I thought about variable separation but I don't know what would be the solution.

Comment: $$\phi \propto e^{i (k_{x} x + k_{y} y)}, \quad k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2} = k^{2}$$

Comment: That's the [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) (the eigenvalue problem for the Laplace operator), and a reasonably complete answer is probably too long for a site like this; see some PDE textbook instead (maybe Strauss, for instance). Anyway, you'll need to specify on what domain do you want to solve it, and with what boundary conditions, since that has a huge impact on the answer.